# Javadoc ignore parameter annotation

Tags: javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have functions such as

```
public void setName(@StdString String name) { }
```

Javadoc creates the method as it is. However I want to remove `@StdString` annotations from the doc created.

Expected output

```
public void setName(String name) { }
```

I want to ignore all custom annotations used in the source file. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.